# _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC gives no output at all

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2008, malloc, heap-memory

In debugging a Visual Studio 2008 program, I wanted the heap debugging information as described on the manual page for `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` and related pages.  However I was getting no debug info whatsoever of the format:

```
{4868} normal block at 0x04B82DF0, 69 bytes long.
Data: <    -   4       > B0 B6 F1 00 2D 00 00 00 34 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
```

Many people ask why they don't see file names/line numbers in this dump, but I wasn't even getting the dump WITHOUT file names/line numbers.

It was especially curious as I recalled getting it "for free" before I even needed it in the early days of my project.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this I'd love a pointer as to what's wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that that output comes when you call `exit()`, but I had changed my program to call `ExitProcess()` rather than go through the trouble of killing all the sub-threads that otherwise would have kept running.

I added code to kill my sub-threads, and just call `exit()` now, and have the output.